# Filter sql server table rows using many filters

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called Student with a lot foreign keys that will be used after to filter students(table rows).

The structure of this table is like:

```
  StudentId   GenderId  DegreeId   NatioanlityId
       1            2          2           3
       ....
```

As a student can speak one or more language,the Sudent Table is linked to language table like this

```
      StudentId LangaugeId
        1         1
        1         2
        1         3
```

And a student can chose one or many subjects for exam:

```
      StudentId      ExamId
       1              1
       1              2
       ....
```

In my asp.net page I would like to filter students via checkbox using ajax
for example, student having female and male gender with Degree 1,speaking language 1,2... I filter rows in a stored proc using user defined table,and I have to use a lot of IF statements like this
          if(EXISTS(SELECT GenderId FROM @GenderTable))

```
         if(EXISTS(SELECT DegreeId FROM @DegreeTable))

         if(....)
        else
         if(...)
```

How can I avoid all the IF statements? I have more than 5 filters.It's boring. Any one have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why have you got a lookup table for "gender"?

Comment: Are you generating the checkbox options by querying the DB, or are they hardwired on the page? Also, for the Language, it looks like you want to be able to check more than one language. If multiple languages are checked, does that mean you want to select students speaking both languages?

Comment: That's right Joel.the students can be filtered by one or many langauges.the problem is that is that may be no gender check:filter only for example by language,and if gender checked,degree checked,combine filter in stored proc with join... u see?

Comment: @Joel :by quering DB.actually the filter serves to get the number of students matching my filter.

Comment: Let me think about this. We had a similar SQL filtering problem on a project I worked on several years ago, but yours is a bit more complicated. (We had to handle multiple filters, with possibly no items checked in some of the filters. But I don't think we could have multiple items checked in a given filter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your query is returning a list of students who meet the criteria?  If so one way to do this would be to build a where clause following this format

```
Where 
    (@Param1 IS NULL OR Field1 = @Param1)
    AND (@Param2 IS NULL OR Field2 = @Param2)
```

This can get ugly and may not perform well depending on how many filters are possible vs used and how your indexing is built.

Another option would be to use dynamic SQL.  You can generate it either in your .net code or in a SQL stored proc.  Basically end up with something along the lines of:

```
Set @Query = /* base select statement */
If @Param1 IS NOT NULL
    Set @Query = @Query + 'AND Field1 = @Param1'
If @Param2 IS NOT NULL
    Set @Query = @Query + 'AND Field2 = @Param2'
Exec sp_executesql @Query, @ParamList, @Param1, @Param2
```

This can get even harder to read and debug but it will commonly perform better since you are only looking at the fields that are actually being filtered against.  However if you use dynamic SQL there are some critical points that you need to be aware of, Injection Attacks being at the top of the list.  http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html is a good resource on what should and should not be done with dynamic SQL.

Comment: A good start, but it doesn't handle multi-valued filters. For example, consider the case where you have a single filter, that selects only those students who speak both English and Spanish. For a given student, there is no single field you can look at to determine if he/she speaks both languages.

Comment: True, I glossed over that point.  The way I have handled that requirment before was to build a deliminated string in .net, run it through a split function in SQL and then use an 'Inner Join' or 'IN' critera to filler to rows that match.  Gets tricker if your objective is to find someone who has all of the checked items instead of any of the checked items but still doable.

Comment: @Joel if more than one laguage is selected,i can use User defined table type.

Comment: Thanks Rozwel.the solution with dynamic sql fits my situation